# AWS CLI query S3 bucket names

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I am using this command in PowerShell to list all buckets in my account:

`aws s3 ls --profile xxx-dev`

I need to list only the buckets that starts with some string. I tried this:

`aws s3 ls --query "Buckets[?starts_with(Name, 'aveva-erm-') == 'true'].[Name]" --profile xxx-dev`

I hae two problems:

1 - The results in both commands are exactly the same, so the `--query` options seems to be ignored, even though it is in the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/ls.html).

2 - The output is one line for each bucket like this: `2023-04-06 09:14:38 my-bucket-name`. It is including a timestamp in each line. I would like to have only the bucket names.

> --- UPDATE ---

I had better results with `aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[?starts_with(Name, 'prefix-')].Name" --profile xxx-dev`

Using `s3api list-buckets` instead of `s3 ls` seems to take into account the `--query` parameter. But this outputs an serialized array in Powershell, like `[ "bucket1", "bucket2", "bucket..." ]`. Since I am using this output to chain another PowerShell command, I need the command to return only the bucket names. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you need to switch the single quotes and double quotes.  See the powershell tab at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html  Use Select-Object to remove the timestamp : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Same output, no filtering at all

Comment: @jdweng, no, there's no reason to switch the quoting styles (the `"..."` PowerShell string here contains nothing that could cause potentially unwanted string interpolation); in fact, doing so would _break_ things, because `"..."` has no _syntactic_ function in a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/)  query. Also, you cannot meaningfully apply `Select-Object` to output _from an external program_, given that the latter is always _text_ (a string for each output line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the documentation page for `aws s3 ls` does mention support for the `--query` option, this seems to be ignored altogether. Same goes for the `--output` option...

So instead, you can use:

```
$ aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[?starts_with(Name, 'prefix-')].Name" --profile xxx-dev --output text
bucket1
bucket2
bucket...
```

`--output text` will turn the output into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[*].Name"

aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"

You can try above one

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how to filter on the desired bucket names e.g. using `--query` or grep or awk.